# 500 Error "no app attribute" when accessing Jenkins on weblogic 12.1.1

Tags: java, linux, jenkins, weblogic, weblogic12c

OS: Linux RedHat
App Server: Weblogic 12.1.1

When attempting to access Jenkins on after deploying the WAR,  I received the following error:

> javax.servlet.ServletException: there's no "app" attribute in the application context.

I followed the instructions outlined at [jenkins-ci.org](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Weblogic), and ensured that JENKINS_HOME was set properly.

In Addition, due to environment constraints I have to deploy this as a WAR. Unfortunately, apt-get and yum are **not** options for me.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that the owner of server that Jenkins is deployed on also has full (Read, Write, and Execute) permissions to the JENKINS_HOME directory.

Googling didn't help much to resolve this issue.

Hopefully, this post will help anyone running into this issue going forward.